# iOS app feed removes HTML elements in question title

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios-app-feed

There is a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/156394) with the title:

> **HTML form using <table> or <div>?**

But it is shown in the *Feed* like this:

> **HTML form using  or  ?**

In the following screenshot you can see that it is handled correctly when the title is shown for a reputation notification, but incorrectly as the title of a reply notification.

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Original resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8rcp.jpg)</sup>

---

On the other hand a question title containing "*<string>*" will show up correctly.

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Original resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHjGn.jpg)</sup>

---

It seems that HTML elements, that are stripped in the content editor, are stripped in the title of the iOS app as well, instead of escaping them.

---

<sup><s>I couldn't check this on Android. Maybe someone can verify this for the Android app.</s> Thanks for your help, it works correctly on Android, so this is only about the iOS App.</sup>

Comment: The SE Android app (v1.0.89 - latest) doesn't have this issue. The HTML tags were properly escaped in the comment reply notification.